# 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSingleton'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

I've been registering my dependencies to my IOC container via the program class, but it got messy. I decided to write a DI provider which provided and registered dependencies inside of it.

Before I begin explaining with code, here is the full compilation error VS gives.

> 'ServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddSingleton'
>   Cannot resolve symbol 'AddSingleton'

I tried to be as clean as possible, inherting ServiceCollection class inside `DependencyProvider`

```
public class DependencyProvider : ServiceCollection, IDependencyProvider
{
    public DependencyProvider() : base()
    {
        Register();
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        base.AddSingleton<IContext, Context>(); // this line errors
        new ServiceCollection().AddSingleton<IContext, Context>(); // this line works
    }
}
```

Here is the IDependencyProvider interface

```
public interface IDependencyProvider : IServiceCollection
{
    void Register();
}
```

Can I not do this, or am I just doing something wrong? I really hope its possible, as the solution seems super clean, apose to creating a new instance of ServiceCollection and using the field for it.

Just to clarify the error, I can't access any of the base methods on `ServiceCollection`, like so

```
base.AddSingleton<IContext, Context>();
```

But this line works, when making a new instance inline

```
new ServiceCollection().AddSingleton<IContext, Context>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `base` keyword does not resolve extension methods. What you want to do is:

```
this.AddSingleton<IContext, Context>();
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, +1 for you.