# Base class methods not accessible from outside parent class?

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to code a dependency provider to register my dependencies. I inherit the ServiceCollection class, meaning I should get all the methods in that class, right? Wrong, so it seems.

Ad you can see, I inherit it, register it using the `this.` keyword, but without that it errors.

```
public class DependencyProvider : ServiceCollection, IDependencyProvider
{
    public DependencyProvider() : base()
    {
        Register();
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        this.AddSingleton<ICoreContext, CoreContext>();
    }
}
```

Calling `AddSingleton` without `this.` throws an error saying it can't find the method, while adding `this`. it works as expected. What if I need access it on an instance of the class?

It also means that if I want to access any of the methods outside of this class, I have to duplicate the method inside the DependencyProvider class, which just isn't very efficient.

Here is the `IDependencyProvider` interface

```
public interface IDependencyProvider : IServiceCollection
{
    void Register();
}
```

Comment: `AddSingleton` must be an extension method and not a method from `ServiceCollection`.

Comment: That's because `AddSingleton` is an extension method.  It's not defined in `ServiceCollection` and  you have to pass it a `ServiceCollection` for it to work.  Basically that translates to `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton<ICoreContext, CoreContext>(this);`

Comment: Is there any way to access the methods directly from the base class of `DependencyProvider`, just like I was trying to?

Comment: I thought I had already answered you this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047779/servicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addsingleton/52047887#52047887)...?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's all good to access it inside `DependencyProvider`, what if I need to access it on an instance of `DependencyProvider`, just like it belonged to `ServiceCollection` class? Do I have to duplicate every method I want to access and put it inside DependencyProvider?

Comment: No, you just use the extension method.  The extension method will work with classes inherited from `ServiceCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

Like I answered you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047779/servicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-addsingleton), `AddSingleton` is an extension method on `IServiceCollection`. That means that if you want to use it inside `DependencyProvider` you need to either use `this.AddSingleton` or refer to the method directly `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton`.

> Calling AddSingleton without this. throws an error saying it can't find the method, while adding this. it works as expected. What if I need access it on an instance of the class?

Well, in that case you just use it as you'd expect:

```
var myProvider = new DependencyProvider();
myProvider.AddSingleton<ICoreContext, CoreContext>();
```